# wso2 identity server frozen at login, continues with console error

Tags: authentication, default, wso2-identity-server

Is there something missing from these steps to make wso2 identity server work properly?

- Fresh download of wso2is-5.2.0.zip
- unpacked
- ran bin\wso2server.bat
- browsed to https://localhost:9443/
- attempted login with admin/admin
- web ui frozen at "connecting to localhost"
- Attempted to shutdown the server with ctrl+c at console.
- Got this result:

```
[2016-10-19 10:37:05,427] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient} -  Error occurred while logging in
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method login
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.AuthenticationAdminStub.login(AuthenticationAdminStub.java:659)
        at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient.login(AuthenticationAdminClient.java:64)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.doAuthentication(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:119)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.handleSecurity(AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.java:218)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.BasicAuthUIAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthUIAuthenticator.java:83)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonUILoginUtil.handleLogin(CarbonUILoginUtil.java:390)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonSecuredHttpContext.handleSecurity(CarbonSecuredHttpContext.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-10-19 10:37:05,427] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient} -  Error occurred while logging in
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method login
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.AuthenticationAdminStub.login(AuthenticationAdminStub.java:659)
        at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient.login(AuthenticationAdminClient.java:64)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.doAuthentication(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:119)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.handleSecurity(AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.java:218)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.BasicAuthUIAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthUIAuthenticator.java:83)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonUILoginUtil.handleLogin(CarbonUILoginUtil.java:390)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonSecuredHttpContext.handleSecurity(CarbonSecuredHttpContext.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-10-19 10:37:05,740]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-10-19 10:37:05,740-0400]
```

Comment: This is a strange behavior, Could you try the same thing again ? what happens then ?

Comment: Killed console, cleared browser cache for today, relaunched, repeated login. Seems fine now. No idea why, but it was stuck since yesterday at that one spot even after reloading the web admin ui. It didn't start working until after I hit ctrl+c in the console and it spit out those errors.